# Proof that Derivative of Expected Value is Zero (Using Differentiation show Unconditional Expectation is Constant)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

If the expected value of a distribution is constant, it means its derivative with respect to the values it can take must be zero. I was wondering if there is a rigorous proof of the same.

**Steps Tried**
$$
E\left(X\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf_{X}\left(t\right)dt
$$
Using Leibniz Integral Rule and assuming the density is differentiable,
$$
\frac{dE\left(X\right)}{dt}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{ f_{X}\left(t\right)+t\frac{\partial f_{X}\left(t\right)}{\partial t}\right\} dx+f_{X}\left(\infty\right)\frac{\partial\infty}{\partial t}-f_{X}\left(-\infty\right)\frac{\partial\left(-\infty\right)}{\partial t}
$$
Using integration by parts,
$$
\frac{dE\left(X\right)}{dt}=1+\left|tf_{X}\left(t\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-1+f_{X}\left(\infty\right)\frac{\partial\infty}{\partial t}-f_{X}\left(-\infty\right)\frac{\partial\left(-\infty\right)}{\partial t}
$$
Or directly using the definition of Integral as the Anti derivative,
$$
\frac{dE\left(X\right)}{dt}=\left|tf_{X}\left(t\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}
$$

How do we show these expressions to be zero. Can we take the derivative of infinity to be zero? (Is there a rigorous proof of the same?) And we also need the density of the function as the value tends to infinity?

I am just trying to understand and play around with probability and related concepts. Please let me know any mistakes in this line of thinking and any resources to further delve into these topics.

Comment: You're taking the derivative w.r.t. a dummy variable of integration. You'll have to change your approach to capture what you are trying to convey. Also, the unconditional expectation is always a constant.

Comment: @par Please note I modified the question and the derivative. I suppose the question can be reprahsed as showing that the unconditional expectation is always a constant.  How else do you suggest I change my approach ... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the question: What is uncondtional expectation? On the other hand, as @par said, the expectation of a r.v. always is constant

Comment: @sinbadh Please note, I could be missing something. But why is the expectation of a r.v. always a constant ... If it is, then the derivative of the expectation should be zero ... The proof is asking for that ... Please let me know if I should elaborate.

Comment: $E[X]:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf_X(t)dt$, which is a real number or $\pm\infty$. In any case, it is constant

Comment: @Sinbadh Could you please elaborate why the integral you have is a real number or +/- infinity? If that is so, then the above derivatives I have in the question can be shown to be zero ... Is there any mistake in this line of reasoning?

Comment: By defintion, $E[X]$ is a real number or $\pm\infty$!! Do you know definition of $E[X]$?

Comment: @sinbadh The expected value is also defined as $$
E\left(X\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf_{X}\left(t\right)dt
$$ Is it not? which means, we need to able to shows that the derivative of the right side is zero .. Is it not?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty tf_X(t)dt$ is an definite improper integral. Then, automatically, it is a number, or $\pm\infty$. So any derivative is trivially 0

Comment: @sinbadh Thanks that is a valid argument ... But using the Leibniz integral rule or the anti-derivative... Are there properties of the density / etc. that also give the result ?

Comment: @sinbadh This also means that $tf_{X}(t)$ evaluated at infinity is zero?

Comment: Not, cause you don't know if $f_X$ is differentiable. Then, you can't apply Leibnitz rule.

Comment: @sinbadh That is a good point, the density may not be differentiable ... Much appreciative of the time you have taken to discuss this and clarify my doubts ...

Comment: @sinbadh So the density is integrable (since a cummulative density exists for this definition of expected value to apply) but may not be differentiable hence the above definition of expected value holds ... but we cannot apply the Leibniz integral rule ...

Comment: a) If cummulative density exists, then density is always integrable. b) Expectation of r.v. is a real number or $\pm\infty$. c) Density not need to be differentiable.

Comment: @sinbadh Thanks ... This was very helpful. Now if the density is differentiable ... Then how does the above pan out? Or we cannot / do not ever go down the above path ... since we define the expectation to be a real number or positive or negative infinity.